# Need help translating this htaccess rewrite rule to Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, cakephp

Hi – I've been struggling with this for days. It seems simple but I just can't get it done.

I have a site developed in CakePHP. There's a script that responds to `/css/profiles/g/whatever.css` ("whatever" being whatever, it is actually a parameter that gets passed to the action), it echoes a generated CSS and saves it to `/css/profiles/whatever.css`.

I have a rule in Apache that takes requests to `/css/profiles/whatever.css` and, if it doesn't exist, rewrites the request to `/css/profiles/g/whatever.css` without redirecting, so the client never notices it was responded by a script and that the file didn't exist.

This is what I have in Apache:

```
# Profile CSS rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/profiles/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css/profiles/g/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^css/profiles/(.*)$ /css/profiles/g/$1 [L]

# CakePHP's default rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I'm moving the site to a server with Nginx, and so far I've got this:

```
# Profile CSS rules
location ~ ^/css/profiles/(?!g/)(.*)$ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/css/profiles/(.*)$ /css/profiles/g/$1 last;
      break;
    }
```

}

```
# CakePHP's default rules
location / {
```

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

The conditions seem to be working, because if I go to `/css/profiles/whatever.css` and print out PHP's `$_SERVER` variable it gives me

```
[QUERY_STRING] => /css/profiles/g/whatever.css&
```

Notice the `&`. It means it got to the `try_files` part and added the `$uri` to the query string, and it has the correct `$uri`.

But...

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /css/profiles/whatever.css
```

That's the glitch. It seems it's not really changing the `$request_uri` which is what CakePHP needs to control what controller attends what.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I finally got it working:

```
location ~ ^/css/profiles/(?!g/)(.*)$ {
  set $new_uri /css/profiles/g/$1;
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/css/profiles/(.*)$ /css/profiles/g/$1 last;
  }
}
```

...and at the end:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;

  ... some other stuff were here related to fastcgi
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $new_uri; # <--- I added this
}
```